# Awaiting for all the callbacks to return before HttpsCallableResult completes

Tags: node.js, firebase, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-functions

I am using Firebase Functions with Unity. The main function returns before the database functions finish. I am still new to Node.js and I am still trying to get my head around all the Async Callback stuff.

I have tried CallAsync, ContinueWith, and Coroutines, but the function always continues after the first return (I use Task.isCompleted() to check for that).

My Node.js functions are something like this:

```
exports.my_fn = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    dbsessions.child(id).once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.val()) {
        Create();
      } else {
        Move(session);
      }});
  });

function Move(session) {
  if (session["error"]) {
    return return_stuff;
  } else {
      if (some_condition) {
        dbsessions.child(id).set(sson, function(set_error) {
          if (set_error) {
            return return_stuff;
          } else {
            return return_stuff;
          }
      });
      } else {
      dbaimoves.child(stt).child(dif).once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.val()) {
          return return_stuff;
        } else {
          if (!first) {
            dbsessions.child(id).set(sson, function(set_error) {
                if (set_error) {
                  return return_stuff;
                } else {
                  return return_stuff;
                }
            });
        } else {
          return return_stuff;
        }
      }
      }, function(errorObject) {
        if (errorObject) {
          return return_stuff;
        }
      });
}}}

var Create = function(data, callback) {
    dbdifficulty.child(data).once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.val()) {
        return callback();
      } else {
        dbsessions.child(data.id).set(data, function(set_error) {
          if (set_error) {
            return callback();
          } else {
            return callback();
          }});
    }});
}
```

(I skipped unnecessary data to keep the question simple). It is basically nested returns and database operations, callbacks and functions call each other.

My C# Unity code is something like this:

```
private async Task<string> AddMessageAsync(string text)
    {
        // Create the arguments of the callable function.
        var data = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        data["s"] = text;
        data["d"] = "0";

        var function = func.GetHttpsCallable("my_fn");
        var Tfn = function.CallAsync(data);
        var TRes = await Tfn;

        if (Tfn.IsCompleted)
        {
            JFunc result = JsonUtility.FromJson<JFunc>(TRes.Data.ToString());
            Debug.Log("error:" + result.error);
            return result.move;
        }
        return "error";
    }
```

The codes above resemble my actual code, which calls the function from Unity, the function runs on Firebase and returns shortly (before it goes into Create() or Move()), Unity receives the result (null). A few seconds later the function finishes successfully on Firebase, but Unity does not receive anything about that (or maybe it does, but I can't handle it properly).

I need to know:

1. how to make the main function return what the other functions return, and
2. how to make C# wait and keep listening to the returned values, instead of thinking the task has completed after the first return. It would be even better if I can only return only when the result is ready.

Comment: I wrote an answer for #1 below. Please limit yourself to one question per post, and please read [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as right now your JavaScript code won't work and is still quite complex to follow for someone who doesn't know your app. Isolating the problem in a completely standalone snippet of code is the best way to allow us to help you efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

To make the Cloud Functions code return a value, make sure that each function returns a value or a promise. Promises "bubble up" meaning that the value you return from the most-nested code will be return to the top-level, as long as you have a `return` on each level.

So in your code from a quick scan, you need:

```
exports.my_fn = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    return dbsessions.child(id).once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.val()) {
        return Create();
      } else {
        return Move(session);
      }});
  });

var Create = function(data, callback) {
    return dbdifficulty.child(data).once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.val()) {
        return callback();
      } else {
        return dbsessions.child(data.id).set(data, function(set_error) {
          if (set_error) {
            return callback();
          } else {
            return callback();
          }});
    }});
}
```

I've only instrumented the top-level `my_fn` and `Create` here, to show what to do. You'll have to do the same for `Move` yourself.